# how to install web3 in google colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, web3py

```
!pip install web3
```

I tried like this but I got this error message.

> ERROR: chainer 6.5.0 has requirement typing-extensions<=3.6.6, but you'll have typing-extensions 3.7.4.1 which is incompatible.

What should I do for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to downgrade `typing-extensions` to a version older than `3.6.6`:

```
pip install --force-reinstall typing-extensions<=3.6.6
```

Comment: `typing-extensions<=3.6.6`